# How does a Grails plugin add its own URLMappings?

Tags: grails, plugins, configuration, url-mapping

I am creating a Grails plugin and I would like for it to add its own UrlMappings. The `UrlMappings.groovy` file in the plugin source is ignored by the application using the plugin, so where should these be defined?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#plugins: `Notes on excluded Artefacts`

```
In addition, although UrlMappings.groovy is excluded 
you are allowed to include a UrlMappings definition with 
a different name, such as MyPluginUrlMappings.groovy.
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me.
When I run the main project i get `ERROR commons.DefaultGrailsApplication  - The class [MyPluginUrlMappings] was not found when attempting to load Grails application. Skipping.`

Comment: @CassioLandim The name of your class must be `MyPluginUrlMappings` and not `UrlMappings`.

Comment: @CassioLandim thank you for that comment. I forgot that it's a class and has a Class Definition...